# Displaying multiple quantitative variables without clutter?

Tags: arcmap, cartography

I am working with a set of data which represents total persons at different pay levels. There are 4 different pay grades which ideally would all be displayed on the same map.

I am new to ArcGIS and cartography so don't have many strategies under my belt.

My first strategy was to write a python script to offset each pay grade around the center point and use a label and graduated symbols to express the quantity (It took way too long and looks terribly cluttered)

[image]

I also made a map with only one pay grade displayed and it is much clearer although I really want to make a map work with all categories.

[image]

Comment: You can use Charts to symbolize your multiple values. Layer Properties -> Symbology -> Charts

Comment: Ill try this out! A pie chart won't work because he important aspect is comparing each pay grade to those at the same level in different cities, not the different levels of the same city. Maybe a bar graph though?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to your example problem is to use pie charts to symbolise the data.

Using the symbology properties of your layer you can tell ArcMap to generate a pie chart in which each of these pay grades is represented. The ArcGIS website has a [page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/drawing-features-to-show-quantities-drawing-pie-ch.htm) explaining this process.

The benefit of the pie charts is that they essentially normalise the data so you can clearly see proportions as opposed to just the total values in each category.